# How to use Microsoft Face API?

Tags: javascript, html, azure, azure-cognitive-services

I am getting error, I would like to send the image and receive the data from it. What is missing?

I would also like to know how to create a button to send the image / video and receive the information.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>JSSample</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        var params = {
            // Request parameters
            "returnFaceId": "true",
            "returnFaceLandmarks": "false",
            "returnFaceAttributes": "{string}",
        };

        $.ajax({
            url: "https://westcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/detect?" + $.param(params),
            beforeSend: function(xhrObj){
                // Request headers
                xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
                xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key","<redacted>");
            },
            type: "POST",
            // Request body
            data: "{body}",
        })
        .done(function(data) {
            alert("success");
        })
        .fail(function() {
            alert("error");
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try reading the error message.

Comment: Do you realize you embedded your subscription key in your code sample? **You need to change this immediately.** I edited it out of your question, but anyone with enough rep can still see it.

Comment: @DavidMakogon 
The key is incorrect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The full working JavaScript code with face detect can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/face/quickstarts/javascript#detect-faces-in-images-with-face-api-using-javascript-a-namedetect-a).

> To run the sample, perform the following steps:
>
> 1. Copy the following and save it to a file such as `detectFaces.html`.
> 2. Replace the `subscriptionKey` value with your valid subscription key.
> 3. Change the `uriBase` value to use the location where you obtained your subscription keys.
> 4. Drag-and-drop the file into your browser.
> 5. Click the `Analyze faces` button.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Detect Faces Sample</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function processImage() {

        // Replace the subscriptionKey string value with your valid subscription key.
        var subscriptionKey = "13hc77781f7e4b19b5fcdd72a8df7156";

        // Replace or verify the region.
        //
        // You must use the same region in your REST API call as you used to obtain your subscription keys.
        // For example, if you obtained your subscription keys from the westus region, replace
        // "westcentralus" in the URI below with "westus".
        //
        // NOTE: Free trial subscription keys are generated in the westcentralus region, so if you are using
        // a free trial subscription key, you should not need to change this region.
        var uriBase = "https://westcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/detect";

        // Request parameters.
        var params = {
            "returnFaceId": "true",
            "returnFaceLandmarks": "false",
            "returnFaceAttributes": "age,gender,headPose,smile,facialHair,glasses,emotion,hair,makeup,occlusion,accessories,blur,exposure,noise",
        };

        // Display the image.
        var sourceImageUrl = document.getElementById("inputImage").value;
        document.querySelector("#sourceImage").src = sourceImageUrl;

        // Perform the REST API call.
        $.ajax({
            url: uriBase + "?" + $.param(params),

            // Request headers.
            beforeSend: function(xhrObj){
                xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json");
                xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", subscriptionKey);
            },

            type: "POST",

            // Request body.
            data: '{"url": ' + '"' + sourceImageUrl + '"}',
        })

        .done(function(data) {
            // Show formatted JSON on webpage.
            $("#responseTextArea").val(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
        })

        .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            // Display error message.
            var errorString = (errorThrown === "") ? "Error. " : errorThrown + " (" + jqXHR.status + "): ";
            errorString += (jqXHR.responseText === "") ? "" : (jQuery.parseJSON(jqXHR.responseText).message) ? 
                jQuery.parseJSON(jqXHR.responseText).message : jQuery.parseJSON(jqXHR.responseText).error.message;
            alert(errorString);
        });
    };
</script>

<h1>Detect Faces:</h1>
Enter the URL to an image that includes a face or faces, then click the <strong>Analyze face</strong> button.
<br><br>
Image to analyze: <input type="text" name="inputImage" id="inputImage" value="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c3/RH_Louise_Lillian_Gish.jpg" />
<button onclick="processImage()">Analyze face</button>
<br><br>
<div id="wrapper" style="width:1020px; display:table;">
    <div id="jsonOutput" style="width:600px; display:table-cell;">
        Response:
        <br><br>
        <textarea id="responseTextArea" class="UIInput" style="width:580px; height:400px;"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div id="imageDiv" style="width:420px; display:table-cell;">
        Source image:
        <br><br>
        <img id="sourceImage" width="400" />
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: I managed to do but now to stay the same as the site. With the yellow rectangle on people's faces and with information, what has to be done?

Comment: To draw a frame around the face, you're going to need to use HTML5 Canvas. Have a look at [this tutorial](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/how-to-draw-with-html-5-canvas) to get you started.

Comment: But as the canvas will detect all the broken, do the correct marking along with the information for each canvas of the photo?